# Unable to send emails from cpanel mail server in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send emails from my app to clients using laravel. On testing using mailtrap/mailosaur/debugmail the email is delivered, but when I substitute the .env details with those of the cpanel account, I don't get email on the to the specified email.

What could be wrong?

Comment: have you checked the laravel.log file for clues?

Comment: there is nothing in the file

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible reasons:

- you have cached your config files -> run `php artisan config:clear` after you changed `.env` file
- you specified invalid credentials/mail driver/port -> see `storage/laravel.log` to track any errors
- your hosting provider is blocking outgoing emails

Probably there are many more possibilities here, but you should start with those to track the problem

Comment: What could be the possible reasons for the provider to block the outgoing emails?

Comment: It happens sometimes - provider blocks some ports or some hosts for example and you need to write to them that something is not working.